# HTML: не работают "отзывчивые" изображения через атрибут srcset

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, почему не корректно работают "отзывчивые" изображения, если использовать их через  `srcset` и `sizes` в теге `img`.

Проблема в примере ниже: здесь всегда загружается изображение с именем файла `mushroom_landscape.jpg` независимо от разрешения экрана:

```
   <img 
    src="https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom.jpg"
    srcset="https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom_portrait.jpg 350w, https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom_landscape.jpg 650w" 
    sizes="(max-width: 600px) 350px, (min-width: 601px) 650px"
    alt="test">
```

В атрибуте `sizes` я указал условия при которых должна меняться ширина изображения в зависимости от ширины экрана. Меняя размер экрана я вижу, что ширина слота меняется: когда ширина экрана меньше 600px - ширина слота - 350px, больше 601px - изображение впишится в ширину слота 650px.

В описании написано, что браузер должен самостоятельно выбрать максимально подходящие изображения, ссылки на которые указаны в атрибуте `srcset`. В моем случае, если ширина экрана меньше 600px ширина слота изображения должна стать 350px. Следовательно в этот слот браузер должен добавить изображение максимально близкое к этим размерам.

В атрибуте `srcset` я указал ссылку на картинку и ее размер `350w`. Однако браузер игнорирует и не зависимо от размеров экрана ничего не меняет(остается изображение `mushroom_landscape.jpg`).

Почему? Что я делаю не так?(браузер Google Chrome, Safari, FireFox. КЭШ чистил)

А здесь работают корректно:

```
    <picture>
      <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom_portrait.jpg">
      <source media="(min-width: 601)" srcset="https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom_landscape.jpg">
      <img src="https://webref.ru/example/image/mushroom.jpg" alt="test">
    </picture>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3xo2vr85/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, написано ли такое в официальной документации, но [в этой статье по теме](https://bureau.ru/soviet/20200130/) есть замечание, что **в зависимости от браузера изображение может подгружаться не на лету, а только после перезагрузки страницы**.

У меня в FireFox 84.0.2 всё работает "на лету" - как Ваш пример, так и примеры из статьи. А в Хроме и Опере - только при перезагрузке страницы с определённым размером экрана. Так что, видимо, здесь проблема в кривой поддержке `srcset` у `img` со стороны браузеров.

Comment: Странное поведение. На macOS не работает нигде(хром, сафари, мозилла). На андроиде и ios - также нет. Попробовал на винде в хроме - работает. Не понятен посыл для чего вообще нужна эта опция "srcset sizes". Я думал, что это для мобилок у которых маленький экран, чтобы можно было  правильно спозиционировать изображения и заодно меньше расходовать трафик. Но если это работает только на десктопной винде - смысла получается нУль))

Comment: @Pavel я думаю, не случайно поэтому в html5 появился тег picture - у него с поддержкой, вроде бы, порядок )